# How can I pass the value from a DatePicker Label to my TableView

Tags: ios, swift

I've a datePicker which stores the value in a variable named `dateLabel` and in another VC, I have a tableView which holds a labelText to show my `dateLabel`. I'm using this code, but gives me a SIGABRT.

**This is the code of my VC which has the `datePicker` and `dateLabel`**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    var Dest:CustomCell=segue.destination as! CustomCell
    Dest.LabelText=dateLabel.text!
}
```

CustomCell is my Class which has the code

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

var LabelText = String()

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    dateLabel.text=LabelText

}

@IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var checkTest: BEMCheckBox!

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

 }

}
```

Comment: There is a lot here that can go wrong. You're setting your tableview cell as the destination for a segue? Do you know for sure that dateLabel.text is not nil? Are your IBOutlets hooked up? Why are you doing LabelText = String()?

Comment: @onnoweb I dont actually want a segue, I just want the datePicker value which I save in dateLabel to show up in my TableViewCell. any idea how else can I do this ?

Comment: Did you implement the UITableViewDatasource methods in your view controller? Updating the content of your CustomCell you should do in table​View(UITable​View, cell​For​Row​At:​ Index​Path).

Comment: @onnoweb yes I'm using this `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCellID") as! CustomCell` in my `table​View(UITable​View, cell​For​Row​At:​ Index​Path)`

Comment: OK, so post some more code of how you've implemented those delegate methods in order for us to help you.